# How can I check whether the message I have sent is delivered or not to a particular user and display in my android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, whatsapp

I want to fetch the delivery and read status of a message that I have sent from WhatsApp using my Android activity. Is it possible to do this? If yes your guidance will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance. This is only for educational purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think WhatsApp does not provide a public API for developers to access or manipulate user data, including message delivery and read status, due to privacy and security concerns.

If you want to integrate messaging features into your Android application, you might consider using other messaging platforms or services that provide APIs for developers, such as Firebase Cloud Messaging